# If a chat message contains a link and is truncated in the star list, the ellipsis points to the link

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, chat-stars, truncation

If a message is truncated at the point of a link in a chat message, the ellipsis becomes that link.

Although normally the truncation ellipsis does not become a link, it's a common design pattern that it does become a link to the full message.

I've [pinned a message in the Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) to demonstrate ([permalink](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23799876#23799876)).

Comment: I don't think I understand where you're seeing the bug here. Would you rather have the ellipsis not be a link? Why?

Comment: It's that the ellipsis is a link at all. I would expect the message to be truncated, and the ellipsis then appended. Somehow the message is truncated, and the ellipsis becomes the link.

Comment: But what's the problem with that?

Comment: @balpha It's unexpected behaviour, and it's misleading.

Answer (score 4):

We don't use the pattern "ellipses in a truncated text is a permalink to the complete content" anywhere as far as I know. In particular the permalink in the "starred list" is always the *time stamp*.

If you have this message:

> Hey check out [this cool link](https://google.com)

and it's truncated after "this":

> Hey check out [this…](https://google.com)

then you would expect the ellipsis to be part of the link. I don't see why that should be different if the truncation happens right at the start of the link. The ellipsis being linked in that case tell me "what follows in the untruncated message is a link".